# Create Group for Google Play Alpha testers

Tags: android, google-play, google-groups

Launching the first test version of my android app, I have followed instructions on creating a google group. Then I return to the Play page where to specify the group. But when I copy and paste my group name and click `Add`, I get the message of `Group not found`. Does anyone have some advice/guidance on how to successfully create a group of alpha testers?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

I found the fix. Instead of just pasting the group name, you have to type the group's email address completely including the `@googlegroups.com` part. So if your group's name is `myfriends` then you must type `myfriends@googlegroups.com` in the box.

Comment: For crying out loud, you would think this is a simple UI thing for Google to get right .... I was trying to paste the Group URL in, email address was fine.

Answer (score 1):

if adding @googlegroups.com suffix doesn't work for you, you might be confused between email contact group with [Google Group](https://groups.google.com/). At first, I created an email group in my contact, and added into developer console, it kept saying that 'Group not found', that made me crazy. Ultimately, I realized that there is another Google Group on earth. :)

Answer (score 0):

Cote Mounyo as far i have used it works perfectly fine, just try one more time and it might also take some time for your group to be available in Developer Console, so please be patient and try again later.

Answer (score 0):

"@googlegroups.com" suffix doesn't also work for you, you might be confused between email contact group with Google Group :(

I used "http://www.google.com/+/learnmore/communities/" instead of google groups